# Не работает функция сортировки односвязного списка

Tags: сортировка, c++, список

Для структуры:

```
typedef struct 
{
int num;
char name[20];

}rec;

typedef struct list
{
rec d;
struct _list* next;

}list_;
```

нужно отсортировать односвязный список по всем параметрам (к примеру, номер)

```
bool isRec_Num(rec * r1, rec * r2)
{
    return r1->num < r2->num;
}

list_ *sortlist(list_ * p0, reccmp_f comp)
{
    list_ *q, *p, *z;
    for (p = p0; p->next != 0; p = p->next) {
        for (q = p->next; q != 0; q = q->next) {
            if (comp(&q->d, &p->d)) {
                p0 = swap(p0, p, q);
            }
        }
    }
    return p0;
}
```

где функция  swap это:

```
list_ *swap(list_ *p, list_ *el1,list_ *el2)
{
if (el1==el2) return p;
list_ *q1=0;
list_ *q2=0;
list_ *q=p;
while (q->next!=0)
{
    if (q->next==el1) q1=q;
    if (q->next==el2) q2=q;
    if (q1!=0 && q2!=0) break;
    q=q->next;
}
assert ( q1==0 || q2==0);
if (q1==0 && q2==0) return p;

if (q1==0)
{
    assert (el1==p);
    list_ *z=el2->next;
    el2->next=p->next;
    p->next=z;
    q2->next=p;
    return el2;
}
else if (q2==0)
{
    assert (el2==p);
    list_ *z=el1->next;
    el1->next=p->next;
    p->next=z;
    q1->next=p;
    return el1;
}
else
{
    list_ *z=el1->next;
    el1->next=el2->next;
    el2->next=z;
    z=q1->next;
    q1->next=q2->next;
    q2->next=z;
    return p;
}
}
```

Сортировка не работает почему-то, или работает, но меняет только 1 и 3 элементы, и то только один раз, второй раз подряд не сортирует (выдает ошибку), либо удаляет половину элементов, либо вообще зависает (останавливает работу консоли без ошибки и без продолжения цикла). Ошибку когда выдает, ссылается на строчку в функции sortlist, помеченную >>>>>>>>>>. Возможно, я в главной функции не так как-то вызываю (уже по разному пробовала вызов):

```
p0=p;
sortlist (p0, isRec_LessNum);
p=p0;
```

или

```
р=sortlist (p, isRec_LessNum);
```

или

```
p0=p;
sortlist (p0, isRec_LessNum);
p=p0;
```

Где р - это list_ *p, указатель на первый элемент списка. Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем я ошибаюсь? Заранее очень благодарна!

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

## include "stdafx.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 typedef struct 
{
int num;
char name[20];
 struct tm date;
 }record;

typedef struct _list
{
record d;
struct _list* next;

  }list_;
    int count_lines(FILE *f)
  {
int count=0;
  rewind (f);
  while (!feof(f))
{
if (fgetc(f)=='\n')count++;
  }
count ++;
 return count;
 }

     bool parse_rec (char *str,record *rec)
  {
record r;
char *x=str;
char *p1=strchr(x,',');
if (!p1) return false;
if (sscanf (x,"%d",&r.num)!=1) return false;
x=p1;
x++;
while (isspace(*x)) x++;
p1=strchr(x,',');
if (!p1) 
    printf("konec zapisi\n");
strncpy(r.name,x,p1-x);
r.name[p1-x]='\0';
x=p1+1;
memset(&r.date,0,sizeof(struct tm));
if (sscanf (x,"%2d/%2d/%4d",&r.date.tm_mday,&r.date.tm_mon,&r.date.tm_year)!=3) return false;

    r.date.tm_mon--,r.date.tm_year-=1900;
memcpy (rec,&r,sizeof(record));
return true;
 }

 list_ *dobavit (list_ *p,list_ *el)
 {
//char *str;
if (p==0) return el;
list_ *q=p;
while (q->next!=0) q=q->next;
q->next=el;
//el->next=0;
printf("\n sotrudnik dobavlen\n");
return p;
     }
  list_ *dobavit_el(char *str,list_ *p)
  {
list_ *el=(list_*)malloc(10000);//sizeof(list_));

parse_rec(str,&el->d);

el->next=0;
return dobavit(p,el);
   }

 void print_rec(record *r)
 {
printf("%d,%s,%02d/%02d/%04d\n",r->num,r->name,r-    >date.tm_mday,r->date.tm_mon+1,r->date.tm_year+1900);
   }

  list_ *print_base (list_ *p)
  {
while (p) 
            {    
                print_rec (&p->d);  
                p = p->next;
            }
return p;
  }
 typedef bool (*reccmp_f) (record *r1, record *r2);

  bool isRec_LessName(record *r1,record *r2)
  {
if (strcmp(r1->name,r2->name)<0)return true;
else return false;
 }

  bool isRec_LessNum (record *r1,record *r2)
  {
//return r1->num<r2->num;
 return (r1->num < r2->num)? -1: (r1->num == r2->num)? 0: 1;
 }

  bool isRec_LessDate(record *r1,record *r2)
  {
return  mktime(&r1->date)< mktime(&r2->date);

  }

    list_ *sort (list_ *p, reccmp_f comp)
  {

 if (p)
  {
list_ *res = p;  // указатель на отсортированный список   (результат)

    p = p->next;
  res->next = NULL;   // первый элемент в нем

   while (p)
{ // перенесем остаток исходного списка в результат
  list_ *elem = p; // очередной элемент
  p = p->next;  // уменьшаем исходный список
  if (comp(&elem->d,&res->d) < 0) 
  { // вставим в голову результата
    elem->next = res; // голова результата меняется, 
    res = elem;       // поэтому расписываем отдельно
  } 
  else
  {
    list_ *t = res;
    while (t->next) { // бежим по уже сформированному результату
      if (comp(&t->next->d,&elem->d)> 0) // ищем куда вставить
        break;                   // нашли
      t = t->next;    // см. следующий элемент в результате
    }
    elem->next = t->next;  // вставляем после (или в конец)
    t->next = elem;
  }
}
p = res;
 }

return p;
}

    int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
list_ *w ;
list_ *w0 ;
list_ *res;
res=0;
list_ *p0 ;
list_ *t,*p,*elem;
elem = (list_*)malloc(sizeof(*elem));
       w=0;
  char str1[30];
int i,j;
int n;
char mar;
int n_el;
list_ *el;
printf("zagruzit dannye v spisok iz fila dannyx?\n  y -
```

zagruzitn n - ne zagrugatn");

```
mar=getchar();
if (mar=='y')
{
    printf("4tenie dannyx\n");
FILE *fa=fopen("spisok.txt","r");   
n=count_lines(fa);
printf("\n n_l=%d\n",n);
rewind(fa);
for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
{
    fgets(str1,30,fa);
    w=dobavit_el(str1,w);
}
}
getchar();
print_base (w);
getchar();
   w0=w;
  while(w0){
 w0=sort (w0, isRec_LessNum);
  } 
w=w0;
print_base (w);

getchar();
     w0=w;
  do{
w0=sort (w0, isRec_LessName);
   }while (w0);
    print_base (w0);
 getchar();
  return 0;
  }
```

**дополнение2**
то AVP:
заработало с номерами!!!!спасибо большое вам!Ваша программа-единственный рабочий вариант))с меня пиво!

bool  был потому что сортировка не только по номеру, еще и по имени(name) и по дате(date)!по дате тоже прекрасно работает!!тепрь только имена по алфавиту остались, там как раз bool  будет видимо!

Comment: По имени тоже  int (!). Для сравнения можете сразу делать return strcmp(...);

Успехов !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортровка односвязного списка вставками.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ldata {
  int  key;
  char *data;
  struct ldata *next;
} lelem;

/*
  Сортировка односвязного спмска вставками 
 */
lelem *
sort (lelem *list, // указатель на первый элемент списка
      int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{

  if (list) {
    lelem *res = list;  // указатель на отсортированный список (результат)
    list = list->next;
    res->next = NULL;   // первый элемент в нем

    while (list) { // перенесем остаток исходного списка в результат
      lelem *elem = list; // очередной элемент
      list = list->next;  // уменьшаем исходный список
      if (cmp(elem,res) < 0) { // вставим в голову результата
        elem->next = res; // голова результата меняется, 
        res = elem;       // поэтому расписываем отдельно
      } else {
        lelem *p = res;
        while (p->next) { // бежим по уже сформированному результату
          if (cmp(p->next,elem) > 0) // ищем куда вставить
            break;                   // нашли
          p = p->next;    // см. следующий элемент в результате
        }
        elem->next = p->next;  // вставляем после (или в конец)
        p->next = elem;
      }
    }
    list = res;
  }

  return list;
}

/*
  Это все для тестирования
 */
lelem *
getlist ()
{
  char str[1000];
  lelem *list = NULL, *elem;

  printf ("Enter list elements (EOF or . to stop)\n");
  while (fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin)) {
    str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;
    if (str[0] == '.')
      break;
    if (!(elem = malloc(sizeof(*elem)))) {
      perror("getlist");
      exit(1);
    }
    elem->key = atoi(str);
    elem->data = strdup(str);
    elem->next = list;
    list = elem;
  }

  return list;
}

void
printlist (lelem *list)
{
  printf ("list:\n");
  while (list) {
    printf ("<%d: %s>\n",list->key,list->data);
    list = list->next;
  }
}

void
dellist (lelem *list)
{

  while (list) {
    lelem *e = list;
    list = list->next;
    free (e->data);
    free (e);
  }

}

// компаратор для структур элементов списка
static int
licmp (const void *a1, const void *a2)
{
  int n1 = ((lelem *)a1)->key, n2 = ((lelem *)a2)->key;

  return (n1 < n2)? -1: (n1 == n2)? 0: 1;
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  lelem *list;

  do {
    list = getlist();
    printlist (list);
    list = sort (list,licmp);
    printlist (list);
    dellist (list);
  } while (list);

}
```

Как обычно при Copy/Paste выравнивание могло сползти (табуляции в тексте ХэшКод не отрабатывает). Где заметил, подправил.

**UPDATE 1**

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -o lis lisort.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./lis
Enter list elements (EOF or . to stop)
1 a
1 b
100 a
2 a
2c
100 x
.
list:
<100: 100 x>
<2: 2c>
<2: 2 a>
<100: 100 a>
<1: 1 b>
<1: 1 a>
list:
<1: 1 b>
<1: 1 a>
<2: 2c>
<2: 2 a>
<100: 100 x>
<100: 100 a>
Enter list elements (EOF or . to stop)
.
list:
list:
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!буду пробовать!!!

Comment: местами переставляет элементы, но сортировка так и не получилась....

Comment: У меня работает. Пример в **UPDATE 1** моего ответа. 

Что именно не работает  у Вас. Приведите ввод-вывод.

Comment: сюда не влезло, в дополнении к вопросу полный текст функции(чтобы не путаться в аналогиях. рассматриваю пока только на примере сортировки по номеру Num.

в файле который грузится в список:

    15,Ivanov,15/03/1988
    33,Fedorov,18/03/1979
    66,dhdfh,02/02/2012
    22,sdfg,03/03/2000
    2,ucfxfg,02/11/2002
    10,kjghjfg,06/06/2000

соответственно все распарсивает в список. на выходе после сортировки по номеру получаю последовательность

  15
  10
  2
  22
  66
  33
плюс соответствующие строки конечно. факт работы на лицо, не понимаю только почему не до конца отрабатывает по смыслу...

Comment: @новичок в си, пожалуйста еще раз и **внятно**.  Не работает моя (*Сортровка односвязного списка вставками.*) ?  Ниже пример сортировки ей Ваших данных:


    <2: 2,ucfxfg,02/11/2002>
    <10: 10,kjghjfg,06/06/2000>
    <15: 15,Ivanov,15/03/1988>
    <22: 22,sdfg,03/03/2000>
    <33: 33,Fedorov,18/03/1979>
    <66: 66,dhdfh,02/02/2012>
    Enter list elements (EOF or . to stop)

Или какая-то из Ваших ???  Какую программу смотреть ? Отметьте ее какой-нибудь особой пометкой.

Comment: Функции компараторы **должны быть типа int а не bool**. У Вас, например, 

     bool isRec_LessNum (record *r1,record *r2)
      {
    //return r1->num<r2->num;
     return (r1->num < r2->num)? -1: (r1->num == r2->num)? 0: 1;
     }

Результат return будет на самом деле **всегда** преобразовываться в 0 или 1 (что -1 (меньше), что 1(больше)). 

Замените bool на int.

Comment: заработало с номерами!!!!а сортировка по алфавиту имен тоже компаратор int??

Comment: @новичок в си, в общем списке вижу, что Вы обновили тему 9 минут назад. Но, тут (по крайней мере у меня) изменений (например Ваших комментариев) почему-то нет (?).

Попробуйте добавлять свои вопросы-ответы в конец **своего вопроса**. Только помечайте их, пожалуйста, типа **msg-1**, **msg-2** и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Вы знаете, сложно ответить на этот вопрос. Как я понимаю, сортировка самая примитивная

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) 
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        ...
```

Во многих случаях это хуже пузырьковой, ну да не в этом дело. Логику swap я понять не мог (да и не пытался). Слишком сложно. Всё, что от нее требуется -- взаимно поменять значения p->d и q->d. Например:

```
swap(list_ *p, lisp_ *q) {
     rec w;
     memcpy(&w, &p->d, sizeof(rec));
     memcpy(&p->d, &p->q, sizeof(rec));
     memcpy(&p->q, &w, sizeof(rec));
}
```

если не наврал.
Если же Вы не хотите перемещать rec d, а желаете обойтись только заменой указателей, то учтите, что перемещаться будет и первый элемент, т.е. Вам надо будет иметь "пустую"  (с незаполненным полем d) голову, чтобы было где поменять указатель на первый элемент.  И указатели на предшествующие элементы не стоит искать в swap (там это лишние вычисления), а брать из sortlist (там можно и сравнивать не p->d с q->d, а p->next->d с q->next->d). Ну вроде всё.

И ещё. Вашы assert'ы выглядят как-то уж очень подозрительно. Там явно ошибки.

Добавлено:
Пустая голова -- просто экземпляр list_, поле d которого не используется. Для хранения одного элемента нужен список длиной 2, 2 эл -- список из трёх и т.д.
[image]

Обработка начинается с p = p0 и завершается, когда p->next == 0 (да и то, из-за того, что q = p->next (==0) это значение не обрабатывается.

```
list_ *sortlist (list_ *p0, reccmp_f comp) {
    list *q, *p;
    for (p=p0; p->next != 0; p = p->next)
        for (q=p->next; q->next != 0; q=q->next)
            if (comp(&q->next->d, &p->next->d)) swap(p, q);
}
void swap(list_ *p, list_ *q) {
    list_ *w;
    w = p->next;
    p->next = q->next;
    q->next = w;
    w = p->next->next;
    q->next->next = p->next->next;
    p->next->next = w;
}
```

**Добавлено после комментария @avp.** Последний текст -- бред. Спасибо @avp . Со связными списками так делать нельзя, сразу рушится структура. Приношу свои извинения.

Очередное добавление. Сортировка пузырьком, так же с пустой головой. На картинке -- объяснение, как перемещаются линки при перестановке соседних элементов (с адресами p->next и q->next). А с первоначальным вариантом и разбираться неохота. Уж он-то точно для связных списков не подходит.
[image]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    int num;
    char name[20];
} rec;

typedef struct list {
    rec d;
    struct list * next;
} list_;

typedef int reccmp_f (rec *r1, rec *r2);

int isRec_Num (rec *r1,rec *r2) {
    return r1->num<r2->num;
}


list_ *sortlist (list_ *p0, reccmp_f *comp) {
    list_ *q, *p, *w;
    int wasExchange;
    do {
        wasExchange = 0;
        for (p=p0; p->next->next != 0; p = p->next) {
            q = p->next;
            if ((*comp) (&q->next->d, &p->next->d)) {
                w=q->next;
                q->next=q->next->next;
                w->next=q;
                p->next = w;
                wasExchange = 1;
                //p=q;
            }
        }
    } while (wasExchange);
    return p0;
}

int main() {
    list_ *l = malloc(sizeof(list_));
    int i, nums[] = {1, 4, 2, 4, 6, 3};
    list_ *p;
    for (i=0, p=l; i < sizeof nums/sizeof(int); i++) {
        p->next = malloc(sizeof(list_));
        p=p->next;
        p->d.num = nums[i];
    }
    p->next = 0;
    sortlist(l, &isRec_Num);
    for(p=l; p->next; p=p->next)
        printf("%d\n", p->next->d.num);
}
```

Comment: IMHO сортировка списка, в которой требуется swap, это **нечто странное**. Обмен данными при сохранении порядка элементов списка совсем не очевидна. 

Упорядочивание же списка перестанлвкой его элементов неэффективна, IMHO потребует длинного кода и чревата ошибками.

Реально Вам надо реализовать сортировку вставками в список. Идея состоит в том, что Вы последовательно выбираете элементы начального списка (сдвигаете его голову) и вставляете их в новый (первоначально пустой) список (результат) в нужном порядке. Потом возвращаете указатель на новый список.

-- мало места --

Comment: спасибо! да, я уверена теперь что ошибка именно в том, что перемещается первый элемент. Если я правильно вас поняла, это устраняется сравнением p->next->d с q->next->d. Обязательно попробую! будет ли он при этом сравнивать первый элемент(он ведь p->d). и как в моем случае организовать пустую голову, подскажите, пожалуйста?
с ассертами полностью согласна, компилирую с закоменчеными большей частью!

еще раз спасибо!

Comment: -- продолжение --

Применяемая Вами функция сравнения **очень странная**. Обычно такая функция возвращает int res (res == 0 элементы равны, res < 0 первый меньше, res > 0 первый больше второго).

Для примера посмотрите man qsort.

Comment: @новичок в си плюс я по ошибке поставил -- мышом промахнулся. Ответ дополнен

Comment: @alexlz, Вы уверены, что swap() в "Добавлено" работает ? 

Полчаса, наверное, смотрел. Не понимаю. 

У меня получается что для списка из 2-х элементов (голова фиктивная, как Вы описываете), которые надо переставить первый просто теряется.

Comment: @avp Да уж. Обшибку пускал. Ответ дополнен.

Comment: С односвязными списками многие операции в достаточно обобщенном виде (**и эффективно**) программируются с трудом. Если круг операций (хорошо реализуемых) заранее неизвестен (предположительно может расширяться) я использую двусвязные.

**Автор вопроса**, если текст сортировки односвязного списка нужен, откликнитесь, положу код.

Comment: еще нужен...

Comment: Добавлен вариант (вроде рабочий). Сортировка пузырьковая